# Ubuntu 14.04 Slow, High CPU Usage

Tags: 14.04, cpu

I experienced CPU strange behavior after installing Ubuntu 14.04, at 5 or 10 minutes, CPU usage suddenly increased about 50%, that's really slow my laptop down (Ubuntu 13.10 worked fine by the way)

Here is my laptop specs :
ASUS A43SA
Intel Core i3-2330M 2.20 GHz
4 GB of RAM

I noticed this when the first installation, even after I disabled online and file search, even after I switch to GNOME 3, and even after I used GNOME Fallback Session, how to solve this?

Comment: i think the only one problem behind ubuntu 14.04 is Unity,try to change its default DE to another lighter one..

Comment: did you type `top` in terminal to see what uses cpu?

Answer (score 1):

ps aux|sort -k 4|tail -n 10

This will give you the ten highest memory using tasks. That will give you a clue where to look.

Comment: The question is about CPU usage, not Memory.

Comment: It's fairly rare that a task using 1% memory would occupy a great deal of the cpu. It's a good place to start.

ps aux|sort -k 3|tail -n 10 will sort by cpu